# No choice of audio output device

Tags: 12.04, sound, hdmi, tv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu refuses to output audio via HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi)

In ubuntu 11.10, in system settings -> sound, under the output tab, there was a menu to select the audio output device, so I could connect my laptop to my TV and select if I wanted to use the laptops speakers or use the HDMI, and the TV's speakers.

I am now using ubuntu 12.04, I just connected the hdmi cable to my laptop and TV, and all I see in settings -> sound is this:

[image]

Any idea how to select to use TV's speakers?

Comment: Are you using an nvidia video card to do the hdmi out?

Comment: How can I find out?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure it is a little late, but I thought I'd post a comment to help those browsing.  I am running the NVidia driver, and when I plug in HDMI I first have to make sure the secondary display is enabled, thus activating the entire HDMI setup (including audio).  Once the video is enabled and working, the sound settings includes the additional HDMI/DisplayPort audio output option.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing program "PulseAudio Volume Control" (`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`) and in tab "Configuration" select profile mentioning HDMI.