# No choice for HDMI audio output

Tags: sound, hdmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Ubuntu refuses to output audio via HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi)

My issue is that I can't get sound to my TV which I connected via HDMI cable to my HP Pavilion g6 Laptop running under OS Ubuntu 12.04-64bit.

Terminal output about audio hardware:

#### **List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices:**

```
jg-laptop@JG-Laptop:~$ aplay -l
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], 
device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], 
device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

OR

```
jg-laptop@JG-Laptop:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
0 [Generic ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0544000 irq 44     
1 [Generic_1 ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0540000 irq 16
```

I have no choice in System `Settings -> Sound` to select HDMI audio output

[image: No HDMI audio]

Please can somebody tell me what is missing and what I would have to do?

Comment: Possible Duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/153553/62483

Comment: you should update your graphics card .

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing program "PulseAudio Volume Control" (`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`) and in tab "Configuration" select profile mentioning HDMI.