# How do I output audio through HDMI?

Tags: sound, ati, hdmi

having a bit of an issue with getting audio to go through HDMI. Here are the base specs:

OS: Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.1 x64
CPU: AMD A10-5800K 3.8G 4M FM2 R
Mobo: MSI FM2-A75MA-E35
OS: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Vid Card: (integrated on CPU) AMD Radeon HD 7660D

HDMI sound works fine under Win7 (after mobo and vid drivers are installed), so it's not physically broken. Audio through the normal headphone jacks works fine under Ubuntu.

Looking at the audio panel, there is no HDMI output at all.
aplay -l also reports only:

```
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

In additional drivers there are two versions:

```
ATI/AMD PROPRIETARY FGLRX GRAPHICS DRIVER
ATI/AMD PROPRIETARY FGLRX GRAPHICS DRIVER (post-release update)
```

The first installs, but problem persists. I do get more resolutions to pick from.
Second version does not, reporting it failed installation and to find details at:
 /var/log/jockey.log

Looked at the log, and it's insanely long, if necessary I can get it to you guys.

Did more research and some had luck by manually installing the drivers, so tried to give that a shot by following this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#Manually_installing_Catalyst_12.6

starting at 3.1 Manually installing Catalyst 12.6.
I immediately had 2 issues, (1) the AMD website does not provide any drivers for Linux, and (2) the following command did not work:

```
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-12-6-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise

sh: 0: Can't open amd-driver-installer-12-6-x86.x86_64.run
```

Some other posts stated to update "alsa-drivers", but that also did not work as install command for the new version of them did not work. I forget the exact issue, but similar to above, cannot open / cannot find.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu refuses to output audio via HDMI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi)

Comment: not a duplicate, I have no HDMI in aplay -l

Comment: found what the issue with "alsa" update was:
uname -r = 3.2.0-34-generic
result = Unable to locate package linux-alsa-driver-modules-3.2.0-34-generic

Comment: please answer your own question using the answer facility below and accept you answer.  Its great your issue is resolved

Comment: ehm, no, it's not the solution, I just posted what my issue with upgrading alsa was. There is still no solution for alsa, nor manual install, nor the overall issue of no audio through HDMI, nothing has been solved. Actually nobody has even bothered taking a crack at it... :(

Comment: @ Boggart (sorry site did not let me reply the normal way) Thanks for the info, but that did not work. Not sure if this (options snd-hda-intel model=auto) is for Intel only, while my CPU is AMD. My post does work, for me at least, but it does have the issue that every time I cut power to the machine (power off and unplug) it does reset, and remove the HDMI audio out. I would love to find a way to make the audio HDMI out persistent.

Comment: Check also Super User [how to listen to audio with HDMI on the TV on linux](https://superuser.com/questions/622115/how-to-listen-to-audio-with-hdmi-on-the-tv-on-linux).

Answer (score 1):

up vote 0 down vote

Does not work on. you don't help people like this!

Ubuntu disable and hide digital audio output SPDIF in all Realtek / Nvidia Cards by default in fact it does same in all flavor of Ubuntu because no body cares the final user.

The prosedure to fixit is the same in all verssion of ubuntu and works for all sound cards Ati Nvidia Realtek Creative Bosse etc. You need to edit a file to do work get a terminal and tipe this

sintax: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (enter)

then add this line to the end of the file

sintax: options snd-hda-intel model=auto (then use the end page controls to rewrite and save the file, then exit console)

At this time you need to reboot the machine, and then realize the missing digital audio spdif its work! go to task bar icon to select propper devise (its show now) to avoid get sound for all speackers at same time. if you need mute ubuntu alets or whatever you need to do enjoy.

for spanish take this link: http://www.fermu.com/es/articulos/linux/48-ubuntu/773-configurar-audio-hdmi-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-una-tarjeta-gr%C3%A1fica-nvidia-geforce-8600m-gt-en-ubuntu

Boggart Akerley NASA Space Ship Program Sofware Engineer.

Answer (score 0):

A guy on ubuntuforums.org was able to point me in the right way: install Pulse Audio Volume Control.

My particular solution was this:

go to the daily ALSA buids:

https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages

download my version: ~precise1

get the .deb file with _all.deb ending.

In the terminal, go to the folder where you d/l the .deb file, and running the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

Restart your machine, once back in, go to the audio control panel, and set it to HDMI.

Note: my comp ~froze~ (non-responsive windows, but mouse was ok) for about 10-20 seconds, then un-froze and worked fine.

Comment: that remove all drivers for me

Answer (score 0):

This was cross-site duplicated on Super User [How to listen to audio with HDMI on the TV on Linux](https://superuser.com/a/622137/1192848), the question here (2012) was asked earlier than there (2013). The question here does not have this quick answer that I needed, perhaps since in 2012, it was still another thing.

Mind in your voting that all of this is just copied from the cross-site duplicate. Since cross-site duplicates do not get closed, I want to share the Super User answer here before anyone else runs into the two other answers here without knowing how to fix it in the end like it happened to me.

- Go to the sound (German: Klang) settings and then
- choose output (German: Ausgang):

[image]

And click on the HDMI output.