# How to get HDMI audio to TV working on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, sound, hdmi

I am still struggling to even see an HDMI connector for audio on Ubuntu 12.04.  Video through the HDMI works fine, using the nvidia-experimental-310 driver(s).  I lean towards thinking that some basic audio driver or audio entry missing, since there is no HDMI related audio output to select anywhere via GUI.  Sound plays fine through the laptop itself, it's through the HDMI line that is the problem.

The current set of answers posted speak to similar problem but don't solve it for me, for example:

- doesn't work [How do I output audio through HDMI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226090/how-do-i-output-audio-through-hdmi))
- most answers with pavucontrol are not the answer, as there is only the "Built In Audio" showing up.

Things I have learned (done this on two machines, 10.04 with HDMI, no sound, now 12.04)

- bumblebee doesn't seem to help video or audio.   I've removed it.
- only the nvidia-experimental-310 seems to get the dual display via HDMI (to a Toshiba monitor) working right.
- Some threads talk about keeping the connector in before boot, this does not impact anything for me.
- Raw control through HDMI works with sound via Windows 7

My specifics:

```
- Ubuntu 12.04
- HP Eliteboox 8530w, uses NVidia Quaddro video card
- 'lspci | grep audio' gives null
- 'lspci | grep -i HDMI' gives null.
- Sounds settings, Output, shows only "Analog Output/ Built in Audio"
- 'aplay -l' output
     **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
     card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD198x Analog [AD198x Analog]
        Subdevices: 0/1
        Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Suggestions welcome :-)