# no hdmi audio in 13.04 (more specific)

Tags: 13.04, sound, hdmi

I know this question has been asked a million times, but none of the things I've tried from other answers have worked. I've got a Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series] audio device and I've installed "PulseAudio Volume Control" after reading this thread https://askubuntu.com/a/232407/45985 and I can see "Radeon HD 6400" listed in the output devices and see the volume meter moving when I try to playback audio, but nothing comes through the speakers.
`aplay -l` outputs:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 3: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

[Screenshot of `alsamixer`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfilxbf4g8778k1/Screenshot%20from%202013-07-28%2012%3A02%3A57.png)

I can also see the "output bar" moving as if it were playing audio, but still no sound from the speakers...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line in /etc/default/grub from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.audio=1"` then run `update-grub` and restart.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same symptom and the problem turned out to be that the spdif outputs were muted in alsamixer.

Comment: I added a link to a screenshot of my alsamixer. The spdifs aren't muted, but they don't have any volume scales...

Comment: Looking at the screen shot, the only other thing I have that is different is that I have auto mute disables.

Comment: Disabled auto-mute and no change. Thanks though...