# Sound not working on ubuntu 16.04 with HDMI monitor

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

As the title says, sound is not coming out even though the HDMI connection is being recognized. I've followed whats mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi) anda [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512482/error-installing-oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms-while-getting-hdmi-audio-to-work-on-tv).

Here is the aplay output.

```
$> aplay -l 


**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've installed pulse-audio with:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

[image]

And it seems to be recognizing the sound, it's just not coming out!

Here is how the alsa mixer looks. I have an nvidia card.

[image]

[image]

I've already re-installed alsa using the software manager.