# HDMI Audio Card Not Recognized in Ubuntu 14.10. How to fix?

Tags: sound, 14.10, hdmi

I have an issue similar to this but no solution I can find anywhere has been any help.

[Ubuntu refuses to output audio via HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi)

Anyone have any suggestions

This exactly:

> I have my PC hooked up to a small 21' LCD Television. When I was on Windows 7, I could choose to output sound via HDMI. The video autmoatically works, but there is no option in the sound settings to switch on the Audio. No sound is outputted.  I have tried each indivicual driver and am currently using the Nvidia 331 driver with updates. Any Ideas?

Here is my aplay -l output:

> **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
>   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC665 Analog [ALC665 Analog]
>     Subdevices: 0/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Tried the speaker test and re installing alsa and puls.
Also tried upgrading dist....

Need help.  Anyone please.

Comment: What output do you get when running `lspci`?