# Missing HDMI audio output(device unplugged), NVidia audio card not detected

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, sound, alsa, hdmi

My **ALSA information** is located at:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=85ca372146c77ccef3fd60151d30fb86dd6c2dcf

*Introduction:*

I'm running **Ubuntu 16.04** with an **NVidia chipset 'GeForce GT 525M'**.

I've installed the **proprietary tested driver** of NVidia, **version 361.42** as suggested in 'Softwares and updates' section. 
I'm able to connect my laptop to my Sony Bravia TV 48W600B using a HDMI cable and I'm getting the video output perfectly.

*Problem Statement:*

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not getting any audio output.

NVidia audio card is not detected. 
In /proc/asound, I don't find an NVidia folder, but a PCH folder(the one for Intel), exists.

*Probes*:

i.)
Command: `aplay -l`

Result:

> `**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
>   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC665 Analog [ALC665 Analog]
>     Subdevices: 1/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC665 Digital [ALC665 Digital]
>     Subdevices: 1/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
>     Subdevices: 1/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

ii.) Command:

`lspci`

Result:

> `00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)`
>
> `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)`

As you can see, there is no HDMI audio device listed.

*Things I've tried (with the help of various other links):*

1. I tried going to sound settings but I don't see any HDMI option there.
2. I tried `pulseaudio -k` but in vain.
3. I opened `alsamixer` and there is no HDMI audio device listed when I press 'F6'.
4. I tried using the command `sudo adduser $Username audio` and got myself added to the audio group, with no effect.
5. If I use the command `pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-surround`
   , I get the HDMI 5.1 and 7.1 output option under 'Digital Output(S/PDIF)', but it doesn't work when I test it. Soon, the option disappears when I go back. 
   And I'm not able to increase the **S/PDIF volume** from alsamixer window either.
6. Ran the following utility to get static. 
   `speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3`. 
   Did not get any noise.
7. And finally, I had installed `pavucontrol` and set the configuration as '**HDMI output+Analog Input**'.

[image: configuration]

There is a dummy output and no sound.

Comment: There is a similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008599/no-audio-over-hdmi-on-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050-ti/1011300#1011300

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a zotac micro pc with Nvidia card.  In the end, mine had nothing to do with the Nvidia drivers.  It was a default setting issue in the BIOS.  I was able to access the audio settings there.  Mine were set to the external (headphone) jack only.  I switched audio to the HDMI port, saved and exited.
HTH,

Answer (score -1):

It is not the first time that proprietary drivers for NVidia give issues. In this post https://askubuntu.com/a/117773/805192 a similar problem (maybe the same) was addressed and therefore might be useful for you.

Otherwise you may consider installing a non-proprietary driver, for which I already gave instructions in this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/1029124/805192. However this was a solution for a situation where also the video wasn't working, so it's not guaranteed that will be relevant for your problem.