# External monitor not running with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 965M

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, external-monitor, displayport

I have a XMG p406 Notebook with a build in NVIDIA GeForce GTX 965M GPU.

At the additional Drivers I choosed "NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.57 from nvidia-367 (proprietary)".

When I then switch to the nvidia card with nvidia-prime, my external monitor is not working: Not with display port and not with HDMI. The monitor just says: "No Signal". It`s a 4k Monitor (IIYAMA PROLITE LE4041UHS-B1).

What can I try to get that monitor running?

My Ubuntu:
16.04 with 4.7.2-040702-generic kernel.

Comment: Problems persists with NVIDIA driver version 375.20. 
Can nobody help me?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason NVidia proprietary drivers seem to work badly on Linux. I had a similar issue with my laptop (HP Pavillion with a GeForce GTX 960M). In the end I solved it by installing a non-proprietary driver.

These steps should do the job: first clean up any eventual mess that there might be by doing

```
apt-get purge nvidia*
```

and then you can do the actual installation

```
add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/pp
apt update
apt-get install nvidia-387
```

After rebooting in principle you should obtain a non empty output to

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

but in my case it was empty and that was why it wasn't working. At the boot Linux wasn't loading the relevant modules. This was UEFI secure boot's fault. Apparently the secure boot didn't like the open source drivers and blocked them from being loaded. This can be fixed by going to the BIOS and disabling it (see here for a more thorough explanation https://askubuntu.com/a/762255).

If it still doesn't work you can try to look for these two possible issues:

Some other drivers are not blacklisted, e.g. nouveau (https://askubuntu.com/a/951892).
The file /etc/X11/xorg.conf isn't there. If so generate it with `nvidia-xconfig`