# No Audio Over HDMI on NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 17.10, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I am running kernel v4.13.0-36-generic on Ubuntu 17.10 on an HP Omen 15. I have a hybrid NVIDIA Optimus graphics card. I dual-boot Windows 10, which can play audio from the same external monitor over the same HDMI cable I am attempting to use in Ubuntu. I can see video on my external monitor in Ubuntu.

I have tried [switching my audio output device in Ubuntu's built-in sound settings GUI and Pulse Audio Volume Control](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/), but in the former no HDMI audio device appears, and in the latter all HDMI devices show up as unplugged.

I have had the most success using the proprietary `nvidia-384` driver installed via the Additional Drivers tab of Software & Updates. Using this driver I am able to see video on my external monitor, play audio through my laptop speakers, and boot reliably.

I have tried using `nvidia-387` and `nvidia-390` from [ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) with [`bumblebee`, `bumblebee-nvidia`, and `primus` installed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Setup_for_14.04_and_later), but I can't even boot or see video on my external monitor reliably using these drivers. I observed that `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau` and `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` detected my GeForce GTX 1050 Ti as a discrete graphics card, which I believe is incorrect, but am unsure how to override these settings to indicate that my graphics card is a hybrid.

[I have blacklisted nouveau, because I am unable to boot reliably with nouveau enabled.](https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07#creat-blacklist-for-nouveau-driver)

I installed [NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.25.run](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/130646/en-us), but after rebooting was stuck in a boot loop, so I ran `sudo nvidia-uninstall`.

[I don't have a lowlatency kernel installed.](https://charlienewey.github.io/getting-nvidia-drivers-working-on-ubuntu-17-10/)

[I disabled Wayland in case it was causing problems.](https://charlienewey.github.io/getting-nvidia-drivers-working-on-ubuntu-17-10/)

I disabled Secure Boot.

I tried using kernel v4.15.4, but only found it even more difficult to boot reliably.

I tried [rescanning the PCI bus on the PCI bridge my GPU is connected to](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024022/linux/gtx-1060-no-audio-over-hdmi-only-hda-intel-detected-azalia/post/5216905/#5216905). I do not know how to switch from hybrid to dedicated graphics mode as the author of that solution suggests though, so that may be why it didn't work for me.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

A big thank you to anyone who made it to this point. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/hhfeuer/nvhda#install-using-dkms solved my problem. It leverages [the same strategy linked above by both Ping and myself](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024022/linux/gtx-1060-no-audio-over-hdmi-only-hda-intel-detected-azalia/post/5216905/#5216905). Most likely `setpci -s 01:00.0 0x488.l=0x2000000:0x2000000` didn't work with my hardware setup.

Comment: The whole `setpci` fiasco is cumbersome to configure and maintain. Your link is more elegant and works seamlessly. I actually used the link your link is based on; the solution here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75985#c33

Answer (score 5):

Many thanks to [Rudi Daemen](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1377653/comments/19). The audio problem on my GTX 1060 was solved by his solution. You can try his solution:

1. Create file `/etc/systemd/system/fix-hdmi-audio.service`

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=nVidia HDMI Audio Fixer
   Before=systemd-logind.service display-manager.service
   After=module-init-tools.service

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/fix-hdmi-audio.sh

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Create file `/usr/local/bin/fix-hdmi-audio.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   setpci -s 01:00.0 0x488.l=0x2000000:0x2000000
   rmmod nvidia-uvm nvidia-drm nvidia-modeset nvidia
   sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/remove'
   sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/rescan'
   modprobe nvidia nvidia-modeset nvidia-drm nvidia-uvm
   ```

   and set it to runnable: `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/fix-hdmi-audio.sh`
3. Enable the service: `systemctl enable fix-hdmi-audio.service`
4. Install `apt install pavucontrol` then start "PulseAudio Volume Control". In "Configuration" tab, you can see only "Internal Audio".
5. Reboot. Plug HDMI and play some music. Start "PulseAudio Volume Control". In "Configuration" tab, you should see "Internal Audio" and "HDA NVidia".
   In "Playback" tab, there is a button on the right side of your music player. You can choose "Internal Audio" or "HDA NVidia". Choose "HDA NVidia".

**Note**

After rebooting, you can see

```
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f1 (rev a1)
```

in the outputs of `lscpi`.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. This is one of the many solutions I tried, but it didn't work in my case. `sudo systemctl status fix-hdmi-audio.service` shows that the service ran successfully, but I don't see "Internal Audio" or "HDA NVidia" in the "Configuration" tab of "PulseAudio Volume Control." I see the same options as before, and all of the options for HDMI are annotated "unplugged." I do not see an NVIDIA audio device in the output of `lspci`.

Comment: Have you rebooted after enabling `fix-hdmi-audio.service`? Or can you see some error messages in `systemctl status fix-hdmi-audio.service`?

Comment: Yes, I rebooted after enabling `fix-hdmi-audio.service`. No, there was no error message in the output of `sudo systemctl status fix-hdmi-audio.service`.

Comment: I suggest adding a line in `fix-hdmi-audio.sh`: `touch /tmp/fix-hdmi-audio`. After rebooting, check if `/tmp/fix-hdmi-audio` exists.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried (well, everything you tried) and failed. This just worked. Ubuntu 18.10 on a Lenovo W530 laptop.

Comment: Worked perfectly in Dell G7 with NVIDIA 1050

Answer (score 2):

Note this is for a GTX 970M but applies to 1060 and others.

The problem for me with the `setpci` route is multiple screen resets as `lightdm` is reloaded. Perhaps because I have three monitors:

- 50" TV attached via built-in HDMI hardwired to nVidia card
- 17" internal display driven by Intel iGPU
- 32" TV attached via Thunderbolt and driven by Intel iGPU

The larger problem is complexity of setting up `systemd` and bash scripts.

The `c` language, kernel based solution found on this link: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75985#c33 is far superior. I've included the bulk of the link below with some modifications to my platform.

---

My system specs:

```
i7-6700HQ + GTX 970M
Linux kernel version: 4.13.0-26-generic
Nvidia driver Version: 384.130
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
```

I can confirm that kernel module, posted by Maik Freudenberg [Comment 27], is working fine on my system. Thank you for the fix. The HDMI audio device now works as it should.

I download and extracted the file [nvhda.tar.xz](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=136418). I created the directory `~/nVidia` for extraction.

Run commands in terminal:

```
cd ~/nVidia
make
sudo make install
echo nvhda | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
echo "options nvhda load_state=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/nvhda.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u # This updated newest kernel 4.15.0-26
sudo update-initramfs -u -k `uname -r` # Update booted 4.13.0-36
reboot
```

With this fix, I did not notice any problems with power management or system stability. HDMI audio works at system startup, after resume from sleep, after plugging/unplugging HDMI cable.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

I am using HDMI connected to an external monitor with speakers; had video but HDMI sound output did not show up anywhere, so it could not be selected.  After I ran these commands the HDMI output showed up in System Settings and I was able to select it.

Original Link: [broadwell-rt286 no audio after upgrade to 19.10 - haswell-pcm-audio error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185613/broadwell-rt286-no-audio-after-upgrade-to-19-10-haswell-pcm-audio-error)

Good Luck!