# Ubuntu 18.04 Hdmi not detected

Tags: dell, hdmi, 18.04, xps

I have a problem since upgrading to 18.04 LTS version.After a fresh Ubuntu installation, when I plug the screen on my laptop (Dell xps 9560) nothing happens. On the screen it tells me there is no signal. Here is what xrandr command display:

```
xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Here is the NVIDIA driver I'm using: [Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eOfr.png) (GTX 1050)

Here are my display settings with or without HDMI connected: [Display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oIR1.png)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also experiencing the same issue (different laptop but similar hardware, so likely related). Did you find a solution?

Comment: What happens when you connect the screen and then reboot?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that this is related to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011300/45597), as it is explained in more details [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024022/linux/gtx-1060-no-audio-over-hdmi-only-hda-intel-detected-azalia/post/5211273/#5211273), it seems that you have to enable the GPU's PCI audio function.

Here is one posible solution to this problem, [copied from that other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011300/45597)

> 1. Create file /etc/systemd/system/fix-hdmi-audio.service
>
>    ```
>    [Unit]
>    Description=nVidia HDMI Audio Fixer
>    Before=systemd-logind.service display-manager.service
>    After=module-init-tools.service
>
>    [Service]
>    Type=oneshot
>    ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/fix-hdmi-audio.sh
>
>    [Install]
>    WantedBy=multi-user.target
>    ```
> 2. Create file /usr/local/bin/fix-hdmi-audio.sh
>
>    ```
>    #!/bin/sh
>    setpci -s 01:00.0 0x488.l=0x2000000:0x2000000
>    rmmod nvidia-uvm nvidia-drm nvidia-modeset nvidia
>    sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/remove'
>    sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/rescan'
>    modprobe nvidia nvidia-modeset nvidia-drm nvidia-uvm
>    ```
> 3. and set it to runnable: chmod +x /usr/local/bin/fix-hdmi-audio.sh
> 4. Enable the service: systemctl enable fix-hdmi-audio.service
> 5. Install apt install pavucontrol then start "PulseAudio Volume Control". In "Configuration" tab, you can see only "Internal Audio".
> 6. Reboot. Plug HDMI and play some music. Start "PulseAudio Volume Control". In "Configuration" tab, you should see "Internal Audio" and
>      "HDA NVidia". In "Playback" tab, there is a button on the right side
>      of your music player. You can choose "Internal Audio" or "HDA NVidia".
>      Choose "HDA NVidia".