# XPS 15 9560 use HDMI port whilst bypassing GPU?

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, multiple-monitors, dell, hdmi

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my Dell XPS 15 9560.

It has been a terrible experience.  When I install any Nvidia drivers (following all of the guides and previous answers on forums) my laptop boots to a black screen and won't work.

It freezes on suspend and never comes back but the main issue I have is my HDMI port does not work.

I don't mind not having usage of the GPU power or having to shut down every time I close the lid however I really need dual monitors for my work.

Can I activate the HDMI without Nvidia drivers installed?

**xrandr output:**

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

**xrandr --output HDMI1**

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
warning: output HDMI1 not found; ignoring
```

**inxi -G output**

```
inxi -G 
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 591b
           Card-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 18.0.5
```

**lspci output**

```
lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev ff)
```

The following post did not help me as the only suggestions are install Nvidia drivers, which breaks my OS.

[Ubuntu 16.04 Dell XPS 15 does not detect external Monitor using HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885422/ubuntu-16-04-dell-xps-15-does-not-detect-external-monitor-using-hdmi)

And in this post, it suggests to install nvidia drivers to avoid freeze on boot whereas nvidia drivers cause my laptop to freeze on boot:

[Freezing at login on Dell XPS 15 9560 with Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091263/freezing-at-login-on-dell-xps-15-9560-with-ubuntu-18-04)

I also tried this but it didn't work, probably needs Nvidia drivers installed:

[Ubuntu 18.04 Hdmi not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032513/ubuntu-18-04-hdmi-not-detected)

Any help is really appreciated.

*****edit***** Just to clarify, I also have Windows 10 on this machine in a different partition and the HDMI works perfectly with it.  It isn't a faulty port or cable.

Comment: Install driver 418 only: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/145182/en-us . Do NOT install the binary form Nvida. Add the graphics drivers PPA and then you can select it in Additional Drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your GTX1050 with Bumblebee.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

You'll get better battery life and the HDMI + USB C HDMI is working for me on ArchLinux

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_9560#Graphics

-Source I have an XPS with running Windows and Linux