# broadwell-rt286 no audio after upgrade to 19.10 - haswell-pcm-audio error

Tags: sound, intel, 19.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10, I have no sound under kernel 5.3.0-19-generic.  This is a Dell Venue 7140 with a Broadwell RT286 Soundcard for built-in audio on I2S, (and Intel HD Audio for HDMI, which is working OK).

The audio settings detect the soundcard and speakers:
[image: Sound setting dropdown showing "Speaker playback - Built-in Audio"]

The test buttons are shown:
[image: Sound test screen showing left and right buttons enabled]

But if I press them, the interface locks up for a period.

I get the following error messages in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Nov  2 15:52:23 pulseaudio[2232]: E: [alsa-source-System Playback/Capture (*)] alsa-source.c: Failed to set hardware parameters: Connection timed out
Nov  2 15:52:23 kernel: [11956.051457] haswell-pcm-audio haswell-pcm-audio: ipc: --message timeout-- ipcx 0x83000000 isr 0x00000000 ipcd 0x00000000 imrx 0x7fff0000
Nov  2 15:52:23 kernel: [11956.051463] haswell-pcm-audio haswell-pcm-audio: error: stream commit failed
Nov  2 15:52:23 kernel: [11956.051466]  System PCM: error: failed to commit stream -110
Nov  2 15:52:23 kernel: [11956.051469] haswell-pcm-audio haswell-pcm-audio: ASoC: haswell-pcm-audio hw params failed: -110
Nov  2 15:52:23 kernel: [11956.051474]  System PCM: ASoC: hw_params FE failed -110
```

`pavucontrol` is slow to connect to pulseaudio but shows the soundcard parameters and details as normal.

`alsamixer` shows the soundcard as normal, but adjustments take a long time to be recognised.

I tried deleting the `.config/pulse` directory but it didn't improve the situation.

If I boot into the kernel from before the upgrade, kernel 5.0.0-32-generic, the sound works! \o/  So it's definitely something to do with the kernel.

**How do I get the soundcard to work properly again?**

Comment: This is Ubuntu bug [1846539](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1846539). (Please [vote for it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1846539/+affectsmetoo).)

Comment: Umm @eliah-kagan, 19.10 is not a development version of Ubuntu.  This is *the* kernel that ships with it.  It's not a "Bug Report" until you know it's a bug (and where to report it, hence the question.)  David's answer was very helpful in determining *where* to report it.  And my question isn't "Here's a bug."  It's "How do I get it working again?"

Comment: @tu-ReinstateMonica-dorduh Based on just the body of your question, I admit I'm unsure if I was right to assume your problem was a bug. But now I *think* you're saying you believe it is a bug, and it seems you may even agree it's the bug David Ward mentioned. Questions that describe bugs with the same information that goes in a bug report are off-topic on Ask Ubuntu, even for bugs in stable releases. Questions asking how to report bugs are on-topic, but this didn't ask that. If you think this isn't bug 1846539, I recommend you edit to explain that. (Anyway it looks like this will be reopened.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Ok, this may be a meta question, but I see a *huge* difference between asking *if* it's a bug and asking how to *continue using Ubuntu* whilst a bug exists.  Just because a bug exists and is reported, doesn't make using Ubuntu with that bug any easier and also doesn't negate the need for workarounds, particularly whilst the bug is being triaged or worked on.  A bug report cannot not presume a workaround.

Comment: Additionally, I didn't know what part of the system was causing the bug at the time I raised the question, which makes Launchpad exceptionally difficult to find the relevant bug report.  Whilst I agree it's important to submit and contribute to bug reports, I see that as an additional task separate to asking the question of how to continue using Ubuntu whilst the bug exists.

Comment: @DavidWard Regarding your edit in the answer of this post, I have rejected it as an attempt to reply. Instead of editing, could you please post your edit as an answer, perhaps with some instructions or additional info?

Answer (score 0):

At this particular point, the bug is reported (thanks @DavidWard) and known as bug [1846539](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1846539).

The only workaround at this point appears to be to use a kernel before version 5.2.0rc2, which, unfortunately doesn't ship with Ubuntu 19.10, so a manual install of an earlier kernel may be required.