# No sound in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, 17.10

I just installed 17.10 from DVD an I hear no sound. I have sound in Windows. I had the same problem with 16.04, and I had the change the grub from splash to radeon.audio.1. This was the solution. This donesn't work in this distribution. I have Radeon RX460 graphics and the sound comes from the HDMI port.

Please help me, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **Settings Panel**, under the tab **Sound**, you can choose the device for the **Sound Output**.

You can look the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-usespeakers.html) to know how to use different sound output.

Comment: Thanks. I have no HDMI output. How can I get this work?

Comment: Line output works, with my soundcard. I's okay, thanks again.

Comment: Line output works but background noise "brrrr" is louder the music. What should I do? I can't find the answer on the net.

Comment: I hear background noise even if I dont play music. Constant "brrrr". I must unplug the cord.

Comment: I think that the noise depends on your hardware configuration.

Comment: It's getting better. I increased the output volume to 100%, now I can't hear the "brrrr" noise in the backgroud, while music is on. When the music is not so loud or I don't listen to music I still can hear the "brrrrr" noise.  I think HDMI output is the solution, but I don't have it. I don't know why is so difficult to set up the sound in 17.10.

Comment: You can accept the answer, if it helped. Thx.

Comment: I don't know how to accept the answer, I'll figure it out.

Now there is no sound at all. No line output, no HDMI. Plese help, I don't want to go back to windows.

Comment: Somehow analog line output and analog headphone is available again. Finally I can hear the guitar music of my best friend. No way I go back to windows. Please help me with the HDMI output, thank you.

Comment: Still no HDMI output. Pls help.

Comment: Maybe, you can find useful this [Ubuntu refuses to output audio via HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I installed Ubuntu 17.10 64bit twice. The first time after struggling a lot I found the solution that worked both the times. My solution was to use pavucontrol. Install it using : sudo apt install pavucontrol . Then run pavucontrol and click on the > sign at the top right till you come to the "Configuration" tab. Select the profile "Analog Stereo Duplex (unplugged)" for Built-in Audio.

Comment: **DO NOT** post your answer to multiple questions.  If the questions are all solved by the same solution, *and* the questions are similar enough to each other, flag the other questions as duplicates of this one.  DO NOT repeat your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Instal PulseAudio Volume Control

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Go to the configuration tab and choose any of the "analog stereo" profiles under "Built-in Audio". If it's already set to one of these, switch to another profile and then choose an analog profile so pavu in itself set your config right.

And play some audio whilst you're doing this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
   sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio pavucontrol
   sudo alsa force-reload
   ```

   and reboot.
2. Open the Pulseaudio volume control.
3. Set the configuration as shown in pictures below.

   [image: settings for built-in audio]
4. Set the HDMI settings as below:

   [image: settings for HDMI controller]

Comment: There are [better ways to restore or reset package configuration](/q/66533/175814) than to *purge & reinstall* (see your 1st step).