# no audio via HDMI

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 17.10, alsa, hdmi

I cannot use seelct HDMI speakers as output device.

[image]

Workarounds described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi) do not work. I assume that this is because they address problems with alsa, which has been replaced by pulseaudio.

Graphics card:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M] (rev a2)
```

Comment: Graphics card...?

Comment: It should work out of the box with the integrated Intel but Nvidia Quadro requires a very specific proprietary driver.

Comment: How can I make sure I am using the intel card? I already removed all nvidea stuff, so I am using the open source driver now.

Comment: *so I am using the open source driver now* and that is exactly the problem. That and you not knowing what you're doing. The Quadro M1000M should work with Nvidia driver 384 and no other. With that properly installed you can use the Nvidia X Server Settings to switch cards. It may also be possible to use BIOS/UEFI settings to enable/disable the discrete Nvidia card.

Comment: Yes, I dont know what I am doing. I did not even know I had two cards. Thanks for the hint with the bios, I will try that.