# HDA Nvidia Output Missing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, alsa, hdmi

I need some help from you.

My problem is that I got no HDA Nvidia output from Audio Settings if I have my AOC monitor plugged in during boot.

My setup:

1. TV Philips 29"
2. Acer e950Swn with a **DVI-VGA Adapter**
3. Nvidia GTX 960.

Here are some steps I tried and some screens:

1. [Audio Settings Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpOL6.png)
2. [Pavucontrol Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj7pz.png)
3. [Alsamixer Unmuted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6AX8.png)
4. The solution on this link doesn't help: [Speaker Test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi/117773#117773)
5. Output of `lspci | grep -i nvidia`

   `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] (rev a1)
   01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fba (rev a1)`
6. Output of `aplay -l`

   ```
   **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC662 rev1 Digital [ALC662 rev1 Digital]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   ```

As mentioned above, the HDMI audio only works on TV if I unplug my VGA monitor cable from the PC during boot and only plug it again on GDM screen.

Also, this works fine on Windows without any configuration.