# audio output to HDMI is not working - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

This question has definitely been asked before but I've tried everything I could find and no luck. Using Ubuntu 18.04 here.

The problem is: I have a TV hooked up via HDMI, the video is working fine but the audio is not. No matter what I do I can't get the audio to come out of the HDMI connected TV. I should note this occurs for all HDMI connected devices, not just this particular device.

I've gone through some previous solutions but they are not working. I've tried:

manually selecting HDMI output in sound settings

`pulseaudio -k` to kill the daemon

using `pavucontrol` to change the audio configuration

using `gnome alsa mixer` to unmute all devices/outputs

Some other notes...

I do not see the HDMI device when running `lspci -nnk`

I do see the HDMI device connected when running `xrandr --verbose`, along with:

```
audio: auto 
    supported: force-dvi, off, auto
```

`cat /proc/asound/card` gives me this:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xef348000 irq 13
```

though I'm not even sure what this really means.

`aplay -l` gives me this:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

HDMI / DisplayPort - Built-in Audio appears in my sound settings

Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output appears in the pavucontrol Configuration tab

but neither seem to do anything.

I honestly have no clue how to fix this can anyone please help?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: have you tried looking in your BIOS? I had the same problem because I had HDMI audio disabled in the BIOS

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:
    [Ubuntu refuses to output audio via HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112512/ubuntu-refuses-to-output-audio-via-hdmi?rq=1)

The steps you described work in other Ubuntu versions and stuff but *not* in 18.04
So if you don't need the old 18.04 why not updating? I mean that would be the laziest way.

Comment: thanks, I actually saw that post before posting here and tried everything XD. To be honest, I only upgraded to 18.04 about a year ago and am scared to update at the risk of breaking anything lol but will have to eventually anyways.. I'll keep it in mind